# File directory as variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to get the File directory the script is in as an variable and then split into following elements:
**Example Path C:\Name\Season 1\script.ps1**
Now what I would need is a variable that would be
var1 = "Name" and
var2 = "1" which needs to just take the Number from "Season 1"

Structure will always be the same --> C:\var1\Season var2\script.ps1 just different names

Thanks in adanvce for everyone willing to help me out as I have no clue on Powershell xd

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full path to the currently executing script using the `$PsScriptRoot` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2).  You can then use the [-match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch) operator with [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2) to get the parts you want:

`$PsScriptRoot -match '\\(?<Var1>.*)\\Season (?<Var2>\d+)' | Out-Null`

Assuming there is a match, then the values you want will be placed in the `$Matches` automatic variable.  So, if your script is `C:\MyFavShow\Season 4\Script.ps1`, then the you can get the values after running the above by simply outputting `Matches`:

`$Matches`

Which would show:

```
Name Value                
---- -----                
Var2 4         
Var1 MyFavShow         
0    \Directory1\Season 4
```

Access the items individually like this: `$Matches.Var1`, which would output `MyFavShow`.

A couple of notes:

- `$PsScriptRoot` isn't populated from the command-line, only when running a script file.
- The same matching technique can be used against any path, not just the script root.  So, if you enumerate some directories (using, say, `Get-ChildItem`), you can still match against them.
- `$Matches` does not reset after every use, only if a match is made, so if you *do* enumerate a lot of paths and check each one, you probably want to also check for an actual match before using the variables (as they may still be set to whatever the previous match was):

```
if($directory -match '\\(?<Var1>.*)\\Season (?<Var2>\d+)') {
    # Do something with the values
}
```

- You can reset `$Matches` using: `$Matches.Clear()`